# Getting ClassNotFoundException in Selenium Chrome driver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Was trying to upgrade Spring Boot from 2.7.5; but any version above this is throwing below error.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

Exception originate at :

```
   chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless","--ignore-certificate-errors","--disable-gpu",
            "--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw","--disable-extensions","--no-sandbox",
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage","--remote-allow-origins=*");

WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```